# Does XML Schema makes reading faster?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I am creating a mini DB in XML, where basically people can readonly and find some data. mix of Datatable => custom XML => user read in readonly XML Data through C# => excel add-in.

I usually use very simple XML file when I do this, but I was wondering if creating a chema

```
<Myshema:table name="">
    <Myshema:TimeSerie ID=""/>
</Myshema:table>
```

Would a schema make finding the data faster in the file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in principle, but it depends on the data and schema, and on the engine. A schema gives additional information to the database engine regarding where and how the data lies in a document, and this information can be leveraged when optimizing query execution. Engines may optimize (or not) differently.

For example, if you are looking for all elements named `<foo/>` in a collection of XML documents

```
collection("my-collection")//foo
```

and you have a schema that tells you that this element only comes first in a document, and exactly once, then the database engine can optimize and stop reading the documents after finding the `foo` element.

Note, however, that a schema can also put more burden at either write time or read time, because one needs to validate documents against it.

Comment: Thank you, I guess there is not much magic behind it then. As I am the only one creating and reading the document, I will stick with plain vanilla simple home-made XML. I am using XML.linq btw.